# Changing a class based on the resolution

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi im making a aplication and im trying to make it more responsive using bootstrap. 
I have it working for desktop, but it breaks on the mobile resolution. I fixed it by changing the bootstrap, the problem is it breaks the desktop by doing so.

How can i make a bootstrap configuration to desktop, and other for mobile.

This is the desktop config:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 noPadding formContainer">
```

This is the mobile config:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-7 noPadding formContainer">
```

In case i didnt made myself clear, i want the desktop configuration as a default, but at mobile i want it to change to the mobibe configuration.

Comment: Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using css [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries)